# Django override django.contrib.auth login process

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

views.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def templates(request):
    return render(request, 'templates.html')

def information(request):
    return render(request, 'information.html')

def custom_login(request):
    if request.POST:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            print("work")
            if user is not None:
                messages.success(request, 'Success')
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('login')
                #logout(request)
            else:  
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
                print("error")
                return HttpResponse('wrong username or password')

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    print("check")
    def form_valid(self):
        
        custom_login(self.request)
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ArtisticCode import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'), 
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('templates/', views.templates, name = 'templates'),
    path('information/', views.information, name = 'information'),
]
```

accounts/login.html

```html
<form method="post" class="login">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="login_input">
    <img src="{% static 'img/bx_img1.png' %}" alt="image"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="login_input">
    <img src="{% static 'img/bx_img1.png' %}" alt="image"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send message"/>
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <strong style="color:white;">{{ message }}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  </form>
```

The idea is to display a message in case of a wrong password, but I can't catch the post method correctly. From what I did past few days to try to make this, I found that I need to override the login. I think the function form_valid is the one that I need to override so I can handle the post method

setting.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: I would start by looking at the Django docs to better understand the password validation process. Here's a starting point: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation And, I would obviously tread cautiously into making any changes to the built-in password functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is to do everything yourself without using the ready-made functions, because the password and the name go to the same place, whether you write it yourself or use ready code. The idea from the beginning was that if I use the ready forms such as form.as _p I can't laugh at the style then there was no way to put notification for a wrong password from there I came to the conclusion that is writing everything yourself is best.

changes:
urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from ArtisticCode import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', views.login, name='login'), 
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('templates/', views.templates, name = 'templates'),
    path('information/', views.information, name = 'information'),
]
```

views.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def templates(request):
    return render(request, 'templates.html')

def information(request):
    return render(request, 'information.html')

def login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            messages.success(request, 'Success')
            #login ...
        else:  
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```